# Bad performance when drawing continuously in CustomView

Tags: android, performance, canvas, surfaceview, android-bitmap

**Use case:**

I need to draw hundred lines and a few pieces of text on my view. I need to give a scrolling effect, for which I capture the `ACTION_MOVE` event and redraw all the lines with the updated points. To get the desire result I tried with different approaches but none works as intended.

**Approach 1**

I made a custom class which extends `View`. All the drawing and calculation is done directly in my `onDraw()` method. Since there is so much of operation done in `onDraw()` method, the performance of the app is very poor. I even checked the performance using **Profile GPU rendering** and I can see the lines are very tall.

**Approach 2**

I created a Bitmap and after drawing all the lines onto my bitmap in another thread, I used `postInvalidate()` to draw the bitmap in `onDraw()` method:

```
mBufferedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);   
mBufferedBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);    
Canvas mBufferedCanvas = new Canvas(mBufferedBitmap);               
drawLines(mBufferedCanvas)    
postInvalidate();
```

Since I erase all the previous drawing on the bitmap and draw new lines with updated points, there is a flickering on the screen.

**Approach 3**

I tried extending my custom class to `SurfaceView` and performing all the operations on canvas object in another thread. But since `SurfaceView` uses CPU for drawing operations, the performance will be poor in low configuration mobiles.

Can anyone guide me how to achieve this task with better performance?

Comment: Try looking into [`RenderScript`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html). I have not used the framework myself, but this seems like a good use-case for it.

Comment: RenderScript wont be needed for my use case.

Comment: Don't allocate new bitmap in `onDraw()`, thats why you have fps drop.

Comment: Don't use bitmap operation you can achieve this with Views itself if there is only lines are there.

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to use your **approach 1** to achieve good performance.

An example that sounds close to your use case (drawing lines, a little text and having these update on gesture movement) is [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). This is an open source library that achieves high performance (see [the following comparison](http://support.scichart.com/index.php?/News/NewsItem/View/108/android-chart-performance-comparison) if you want stats)

The classes to examine are the `Renderer` classes as these contain code draw in the `onDraw(Canvas c)` of the chart subtypes. You can see some of the tricks used to achieve high performance there:

1. Don't allocate in a render loop. Instead, allocate outside the loop and reuse/recycle variables. See `LineChartRenderer` [line 199](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/31b60225d0eb8caf49e98b7851794d6532f340f8/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/LineChartRenderer.java#L199)
2. Use buffering. For example, in MPAndroidChart, the points for the four corners of the bars in the bar chart are buffered and the buffer array is reused. See the [`BarBuffer`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/ccf6b7e3b1054a5a47d2822148cc19c14e9c3da6/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/buffer/BarBuffer.java) class.
3. Use the native [Canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) drawing functions (`drawPath`, `drawLine` etc.)

A complete list of tips for optimising rendering can be found in the Android Performance [Slow Rendering Guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render.html)

Answer (score 2):

Approach 2 is the best one. If you see flickering, it means that the bitmap is drawn to screen after you erase it and before you draw all the lines. If this is the case use another bitmap and do double buffering:

ScreenBitmap is what is drawn to screen
OffScreenBitmap is used for drawing in background.

Draw all your lines and text to OffScreenBitmap, and once finished, copy it to ScreenBitmap.
in onDraw, draw the ScreenBitmap.

Create these bitmaps once (typically in onSizeChanged), so that there is no alloocation in onDraw